# how to register MouseClick event on Java Swing editable ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have an editable JComboBox and I want to register or listen to Mouse click event once the JCombobox popup menu is double click. Please avoid register to the loop of JComboBox components way as that didn;t work.
I tried with itemListener but that didn't justify the click of Mouse.

Let me know some logical way to sort out this issue

Answer (score 1):

Add the MouseListener to the editor or the combo box:

```
ComboBoxEditor editor = comboBox.getEditor();
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getEditorComponent();
textField.addMouseListener(...);
```